# Routing error caused by nested routes in Rails 3 project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, routes

**Here's my problem:**

- I have a web app, in which users can create posts.
- User and post are created simultaneously - I extract the user's email from the post to create his user entry. (No password/login/registration etc required)
- In my routes.rb file, I have posts nested with users (see attached)

**Now, here is my question:**

Where should the `posts#new` creation form be? Currently I have it at /posts/new but this is clearly wrong, I am getting a routing error.

Grateful for any feedback.

**routes.rb**

```
Mysalary::Application.routes.draw do

resources :users do
   resources :posts
   end

resources :profiles
resources :pages

get "pages/home"
get "pages/about"
get "pages/legal"
get "pages/feedback"

root :to => 'posts#new'

end
```

Comment: I don't think you need to specify the posts#new as the resources would create the routes for the rest actions.

Comment: Software is (generally) case-sensitive. You shouldn't be using UPPERCASE to add emphasis because you're changing the meaning of the word by doing so.

Comment: It would be helpful if u post your error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would add posts on it own, so to have both you would have:

routes.rb

```
resources :users do
  resources :posts
end

resources :posts
```

Answer (score 1):

You have `posts` only as a nested resource, so you would find it at `/users/:user_id/posts/new`

If you want to reach it at `/posts/new`, just un-nest `resources :posts`. You can also leave it nested and repeat it outside the nesting, then it would be reachable both ways.

Remember to run `rake routes` in the console.